# Ember JS - Dynamically render template from route and append

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ember.js, dynamic

I have a web application (using ember 2.0) with 2 parts. Left menu and right content, both independent from each other.
Navigating to route name "PageRoute", application load the configuration JSON from server, process it and the checks, where should be content rendered:

```
{
...
position: "left",
...
}
```

or

```
{
...
position: "right",
...
}
```

Then I use "this.transitionTo" and redirect it to RightRoute or LeftRoute.
RightRoute is ok, LeftRoute is the problem.

At the beginning - Left menu is empty. When LeftRoute is loaded, it should append (not replace) some menu (rendered template or component).
When the LeftRoute is loaded again, new menu should be rendered from model and append it to existing left menus so it would be possible to swap between rendered menus and the last menu will be visible.
At the same time, when the current menu is swapped, it should be removed from the "left menu list" and the previous menu will be visible.

I've found some some solutions appending View, but the view is deprecated in Ember 2.0, I've tried to do it like here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/defapo/3/edit?html,js,output but Router can't access actions in components (with pushObject) and I've tried countless other methods like using data stores or dynamically modifying the model etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make it this way:

**/controllers/left.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    menus: [],

    addMenu (menuData) {
        this.get('menus').addObject(menuData);
    },

    removeMenu () {
        this.get('menus').popObject();
    }

});
```

**/routes/left.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    setupController (controller, model) {
        controller.addMenu(model);
    }

});
```

**/templates/left.hbs**

```
{{#each menus as |menu| }}
    <!-- render menu -->
    {{log menu}}
{{/each}}
```

In this case when you `transitionTo('left', menuData)` it will append the menu to the list. When you need to remove last menu, you can do `this.controllerFor('left').removeMenu()` in any other route (e.g. in your PageRoute).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works! However there is problem with RightRoute. It is not only append menu, but also erase (rerender) content of the right side. In RightRoute, I am rendering to _{{outlet "maincontent"}}_

Comment: I'm not completely getting the problem with RightRoute. Could you please describe it widely?

Comment: Left is menu, right is content and both are independent. When it transits to LeftRouter, it suppose to only append the new menu and do nothing with rendered right part, with content. When it transits to RightRoute, left part (menu) should be left intact, with all before rendered menus, and the right part should render new content. Hope it is understandable.

Comment: I forgot to specify the problem: LeftRoute is called, menu is added, but at the same time the content, what was rendered before using RightRoute, is rerendered and is blank

Comment: Did it work correctly before? This is how Ember Router works: When you do a transition to RightRoute, it renders right template, when you transition to LeftRoute, it exits RightRoute (and removes its template) and transitions to LeftRoute.

Comment: I moved the content and menu variable to ApplicationController and accessing it through LeftController and RightController via Ember.inject.controller and now it is working! Thank you very much for help